# How to minimize $|x_1| + |x_2|$ via linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming

Given $a_{ij}, b_j \in \Bbb R$, consider the following optimization problem:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb R}{\text{minimize}} & |x_1| + |x_2|\\ \text{subject to} & a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 = b_1\\ & a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2  = b_2\end{array}$$

Can I solve this problem with linear programming methods? If so, how?

Comment: This system does not have a guaranteed solution, is that ok?

Comment: yes, for example if $a_{11}=a_{21}$ and $a_{12}=a_{22}$ but $b_1 \neq b_2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432003/converting-absolute-value-program-into-linear-program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can!
Set $x_1=x_1^+ - x_1^-$ where $x_1^+ \geq 0$ and $x_1^- \geq 0$ then $|x_1|=x_1^+ + x_1^-$. Same for $x_2$.

This works since it is a minimization problem.

Comment: To be more clear: every real number can be written as a difference. If $x_1$ is negative the problem is going to set $x_1^-=x_1$ and $x_1^+=0$ since it wants to minimize their sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the problem up in four parts. One part is minimizing $x_1 + x_2$ subject to your constraints and $x_1, x_2 \geq 0$.

Another part would be minimizing $-x_1 + x_2$ subject to your constraints and $x_1 \leq 0$, $x_2 \geq 0$, and so on. One part for each quadrant.

Each part can be solved by linear programming methods, and the lowest minimum of all is the minimum of the original problem.