# Why is the following not a a linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-programming

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & 3x + 3y − 30\\ \text{subject to} & |x−2|−|y| \leq 5\end{array}$$

This is totally a LLP to me, just not in its standard form. I really don't know why it is not? What I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Notice that the constraint is not a linear function of your decision variables.

Comment: @VHarisop Why the constraint is not linear? Is it because the absolute value? If it is, why can not remove the absolute value by some tricks?

Comment: Yes, the absolute values are the reason. You can't rely on any tricks to "remove" the absolute value (e.g. if you try equating it with a linear function you will end up with multiple coefficients depending on the values of $x$, $y$).

Comment: @VHarisop I'm confused. Since it gives an example that maximize 3x + 3y − 30 subject to |x−2|+|y|≤5 is a LLP. Why only change the "+" to "-", then it is not?

Comment: I would say that neither problem (with the + or the -) "is" a linear programming problem. It's just that the one with the + coincidentally happens to be equivalent to a LPP, and (as the answer shows) the one with the - does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimisation problem in the question is NOT an LPP because an LPP has *convex* feasible region.  We can easily check that
$$S = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2 \mid |x-2|-|y| \le 5\}$$ is *not* convex as $(10,\pm3) \in S$, but $(10,0) \notin S$.

This problem can be converted into an LPP by the usual trick in (2).

1. make the substitution $u = x-2$
2. split each decision variables into its positive and negative components.

\begin{alignat}{2}
y^+ &:= \frac{|y|+y}{2} &\qquad y^- &:= \frac{|y|-y}{2} \\
u^+ &:= \frac{|u|+u}{2} & u^- &:= \frac{|u|-u}{2} \\
\therefore y &= y^+ - y^- & |y| &= y^+ + y^- \\
u &= u^+ - u^- & |u| &= u^+ + u^-
\end{alignat}
Then the objective function and the constraints become $3u^+ - 3u^- + 3y^+ - 3y^- - 24$ and
\begin{cases}
u^+ + u^- - y^+ - y^- &\le 5 \\
u^+, u^-, y^+, y^- &\ge 0 \\
u^+ u^- = y^+ y^- = 0
\end{cases}
respectively.

Comment: your 'trick' is wrong (you can let $y^+ \to \infty$), you cannot convert it into an LPP without introducing binaries

Comment: @LinAlg I've a careless mistake when splitting variables in the middle.  I meant $u$ instead of $x$.  Apart from that, the trick is a usual one.  You may see this, for example, in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/432029/290189.

Comment: The original maximisation problem is unbounded (by fixing $x$ and letting $y \to +\infty$).  Your suggestion ($y^+ \to +\infty$) also leads to the same result.  I don't see how this shows that my trick is wrong.  I'm missing something?

Comment: that your reformulation is wrong becomes more apparent when you add an extra constraint that $y=0$ ($y^+ - y^- = 0$). The original problem is bounded but your reformulated problem is not (set $y^+ = y^-$, letting those go to infinity, the first constraint no longer restricts $x$).

Comment: @LinAlg Why you say that the original problem bounded?  An arbitrarily large $y$ satisfies the orginal constraint.  Since the coefficient of $y$ in the objective function is positive, the problem is unbounded.  I've never introduced $y=0$ as a constraint.  It's $y^+ y^-=0$.

Comment: The original problem is bounded after adding $y=0$, while your 'trick' cannot cope with the extra constraint.

Comment: @LinAlg I don't get you.  The constraint $y=0$ implies that $y^+ = y^- = 0$, so the constraint would become $|u|\le5$.  This restricts $u$ (i.e. $x$).