# Optimization: Absolut value function

Tags: optimization

I want to find the minimum of the following function, using a linear solver in Matlab:

f = sum(((P * x - d)+|P * x - d|))*0.5*p)

x (dimension [ix1]) is binary, P (dimension [nxi]),d and p are always positive.

In other words:

if P*x => d

f = (P*x-d)*p

if P*x < d

f = 0

Is it possible to solve this problem with a linear Solver in Matlab (like linprog or cplexlp)?

Comment: You'd have a chance of being attended to if you write your formulae in MathJax. It's hard to read as it is.

Comment: Here is the [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-questions) reference page.

Comment: Try linear solver. If it doesn't work use a nonlinear solver. There are plenty out there and they are pretty quick.

I think the objective function looks non-linear as it has norms in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting absolute value program into linear program](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432003/converting-absolute-value-program-into-linear-program)

Comment: The only nonlinear solver for binary (or integer) problems I know is ga (genetic algorithm). I'm trying it and it is pretty inefficient. Linear would be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimizing $\max\{Ax+b,0\}$ is equivalent to minimizing $t$ under the simultaneous constraints $t\geq Ax+b$ and $t\geq 0$, so it is linear. See for instance https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/linear.html#maximum

Comment: Ok I do understand this. But how can i set constraints for my function value?
$$f=max((P∗x−d)∗p,0)$$
Actually it is only possible to set constraints like
$$A∗x<=b$$
So how can I set constraints between f and x?

Comment: @Johnny Both inequalities with $t$ from my answer are linear inequalities in the aggregate variable $(t,x)$, that is of the form you want.

Comment: Oh ok, so I will operate with two variables in one Optimization? Like this: $$f(t,x) = t * p$$  Constraints: $$t(x) >= P*  x - d$$ $$t(x) >= 0$$ and I will need some more like $$A * x >= b$$