Solve $\max |x|$ such that $x^2 - 4x + 4 = 0$?
I want to solve
\begin{align}
\max |x| \text{ s.t } x^2 -4x + 4 = 0
\end{align}
Exercise 1 is to reformulate the problem without the norm. This yields
\begin{align*}
\max t \\
\text{s.t. } t-x &\geq 0\\
t+x &\geq 0 \\
x^2 -4x + 4 &= 0
\end{align*}
Exercise 2 is to use KKT-conditions to solve the problem. In my script those are only given for a minimization problem, hence I reformulate the problem to
\begin{align*}
\min -t \\
\text{s.t. } t-x &\geq 0\\
t+x &\geq 0 \\
x^2 -4x + 4 &= 0
\end{align*}
Then the Lagrangian is given by $L(t,x,\lambda) = -t -\lambda_1 (t-x) -\lambda_2 (t+x) -\lambda_3 (x^2 -2x + 4)$. But the derivative with respecto to $t$ leads $-1-\lambda_1 -\lambda_2 = 0$. Since $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \geq 0$ this can never be satisfied. However the problem clearly has a solution namely $x = 2$. How can this be?
EDIT: As it was pointed out in the comments, the reformulation was wrong. Indeed, the variable $t$ is not bounded. I now tried to reformulate it as
\begin{align*}
\min t\\
\text{ s.t. } t-x &\geq 0 \\
t+x & \geq 0 \\
x^2 -4x + 4 &= 0
\end{align*}
Would this be correct? Would this generalize?

$x=2$ and $x=-2$ are solutions? Did you actually try plugging them in to see?

Yes, sorry, there was a typo in the constraint.

Notice that $x^{2} - 4x + 4 = (x - 2)^{2} = 0$ iff $x = 2$.

Hi Atila, yes there was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out, corrected it. However, the problem still has a solution, but somehow the KKT condition doesnt really add up.

Using linear programming for solving such a question with an evident answer ...

the problem is more stated to exercise working with KKT conditions...

Even if you are to work with KKT conditions I doubt that it is required to forget junior high school algebra?

Your reformulation is wrong. Indeed, $t$ can be chosen as big as possible for any feasible $x$. Speaking of feasible $x$, one could also note that the equation $x^2 - 2x + 4 = 0$ is not solvable (in the reals).

Sorry, there was a typo in the constraint. It is supposed to be $x² -4x + 4$.

Could you please elaborate how the reformulation is wrong?

This is already in my answer. In your reformulation, you only have lower bounds on $t$, thus $t$ can be made as big as possible. Thus, the reformulated problem does not have a solution.

Ah I see. But isnt it the same approach as used here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432003/converting-absolute-value-program-into-linear-program

How would you do this for a maximization problem?
